# kendo angular autocomplete template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

Anyone had any succes on getting a template working with the autocomplete?

I tried the example on the [site](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/template.html):

```
template: '<span class="k-state-default"><img src=\"../../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg\" alt=\"#:data.CustomerID#\" /></span>' +
'<span class="k-state-default"><h3>#: data.ContactName #</h3><p>#: data.CompanyName #</p></span>',
```

and a tried about almost any combination in this:

```
<input kendo-auto-complete k-data-text-field="'$id'" 
    k-data-source="all_ledger" ng-model="search"
    k-template="'data.name'" >
```

The syntax for kendo angular seems different on this?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, the correct syntax is:

```
<input kendo-auto-complete k-data-text-field="'$id'" 
k-data-source="all_ledger" ng-model="search"
k-template="
'<span style=&quot;display: inline-block; width: 70px;&quot;>${ data.$id }</span>
    <span>${ data.name }</span>'">
```